# Splitting screen trouble

Tags: html, css, frontend

I tried making a responsive split screen on codepen. When the size of the screen is small, it gives columns otherwise you get two rows. Everything works fine on codepen. But when I try to implement this code into the code of my website, the grey area diminishes. What could possibly be the reason?

http://codepen.io/bellarose/pen/YqGZLL

HTML:

```
<section class="first-section">
<body>
   <div class="container-info">         
     <h1>first screen</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="container-main">
     <h1>second screen</h1>
   </div>
</body>
</section>

<section class="second-section">
<body>
   <div class="container-info1">            
     <h1>first screen</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="container-main1">
     <h1>second screen</h1>
   </div>
</body>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.first-section {
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.second-section {
    height: 100%;
   text-align: center;
}

.container-info {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 490px;
  background-color: red; }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container-info {
      float: left;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 50%; } }



.container-main {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 490px;
  background-color: grey; }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container-main {
      float: right;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 50%; } }


.container-info1 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 490px;
  background-color: pink; }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container-info1 {
      float: left;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 50%; } }



.container-main1 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 490px;
  background-color: white; }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container-main1 {
      float: right;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 50%; } }
```

Answer (score 3):

Incorrect HTML syntax. First, the `body` tag is created one time and you cannot put it inside other elements. `<body>` is the main "wrapper".

**Correct HTML:**

```html
<html>
<head>
  ... metadata
</head>

<body>

  <section class="first-section">
    <div class="container-info">
      <h1>first screen</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container-main">
      <h1>second screen</h1>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="second-section">
    <div class="container-info1">
      <h1>first screen</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container-main1">
      <h1>second screen</h1>
    </div>
  </section>


</body>
</html>
```

---

As for the gray box not appearing, <s>it could be because you are using `height: 100%` without making sure that HTML/body also have `height:100%`. If you do not add the height to body, calculation will not work properly.</s>

Gray box did not appear because parent (section) has a **fixed height of 100%** while the children overflow that height. To solve this you could change `height:100%` of section to `min-height: 100%`

P.S your CSS could be simplified to this:

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

html, body {height:100%;}

section {
  min-height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

section > div {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 490px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  section div {
    height: 100%;
    float: left; 
    width: 50%;
  }
}

/* coloring */

.container-info {background: red;}
.container-main {background-color: grey;}
.container-info1 {background-color: pink;}
.container-main1 {background-color: white;}
```

```html
<section class="first-section">
  <div class="container-info">
    <h1>first screen</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container-main">
    <h1>second screen</h1>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="second-section">
  <div class="container-info1">
    <h1>first screen</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container-main1">
    <h1>second screen</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I corrected the html but it still doesn't work. The grey area diminishes and isn't visible at all.

Comment: @uitwaa I'm looking into. BTW you have a lot of redundant CSS rules. Why do you need `left:0 top:0` for example?

Comment: @uitwaa did you add `min-height:100%` to section instead of `height:100%` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106143/discussion-between-uitwaa-and-aziz).

Answer (score 0):

```
.first-section {
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.second-section {
    height: 100%;
   text-align: center;
}

.container-info {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 490px;
  background-color: red; }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container-info {
      float: left;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 50%; } }



.container-main {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 490px;
  background-color: grey; }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container-main {
      float: right;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 50%; } }
@media and(max-width:767px){
  .container-info1{
    width:100%;
  }
  .container-main1{
    width:100%;
  }
}

.container-info1 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 490px;
  background-color: pink; }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container-info1 {
      float: left;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 50%; } }



.container-main1 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 490px;
  background-color: white; }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container-main1 {
      float: right;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 50%; } }
```

i just remove the width from the classes `.container-info1` and `.container-main1`
and defined the width in the another media query which says `@media and (max-width:767px)`

Comment: I think you should check this again because this doesn't work correctly

Comment: i updated the code pen also here is the link [link]("http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqGVLo") code pen

Answer (score 0):

ok try this now

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>

.first-section {
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.second-section {
    height: 100%;
   text-align: center;
}

.container-info {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 490px;
  background-color: red; }



.container-main {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 490px;
  background-color: grey; }


.container-info1 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 490px;
  background-color: pink; }



.container-main1 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 490px;
  background-color: white; }

    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .container-info {
      float: left;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 50%; } 
    .container-main {
      float: right;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 50%; } }

 @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .container-info1 {
      float: left;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 50%; } 
    .container-main1 {
      float: right;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 50%; } }

    @media screen and (max-width:767px){
  .container-info1{
    width:100%;
  }
  .container-main1{
    width:100%;
  }
  .container-info{
    width:100%;
  }
  .container-main{
    width:100%;
  }
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<section class="first-section">
<body>
   <div class="container-info">         
     <h1>first screen</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="container-main">
     <h1>second screen</h1>
   </div>
</body>
</section>

<section class="second-section">
<body>
   <div class="container-info1">            
     <h1>first screen</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="container-main1">
     <h1>second screen</h1>
   </div>
</body>
</section>



</body>
</html>
```